# PC infection suspected

Tags: virus

I have a feeling that my PC is infected with a RAT (remote administration tool). It all started when I logged on an mmorpg (online game). It's not popular and at this time I had a port open by me going on this game the admins can see my IP. how far could this go if they port scanned me?

Anyway I need to make sure 100% that my PC is clean of rats and backdoors.

Even if there wasn't a way to do so, and my last hope is installing a new OS, what should I do then to prevent reinfection?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal site. I'm not sure where to direct you for help.

Comment: Simply having an open port is not enough for any malicious to happen.  A person performing a port scan is not enough for any malicious to happen.  Your system has to be already vulnerable, so basically, your barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have an updated version of your OS and a decent AntiVirus you should be good against all "standard" attack (any attack a person with google and a computer could do). Just having an IP and a port doesnt make you wounerable to an attack. EX: You know the IP and the port to Superuser.com but you cant easily hack them. The only really "harmfull" thing they could do to you is DDOS you. since that only requires you to know the targets IP. But the DDOS only makes ur internet connection un-useable.